# How to pass column of clicked cell to custom renderer

Tags: click, cell, ng2-smart-table

In ng2-smart-table  that is rendering a custom component, when a cell is clicked the value of the  cell is passed into the custom component but the column field Id is not

Comment: Welcome to SO! You'll need to edit your post to provide a [minimally, reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). In other words, can you edit the question and add your source code?

Answer (score 1):

If you are looking for row information like row id or any other information on the column click then you can use the following steps

Define static variable 
static isColumnNameClick= false;

In HTML template

```
 <ng2-smart-table [settings]="settings" [source]="source"(userRowSelect) = "selectDataRow($event)"> </ng2-smart-table>
```

In setting, you can provide the following information

```
columns: {
  columnName: {
    type: 'custom',
    title: 'Column Name',
    renderComponent: ChildComponent,
    onComponentInitFunction(instance) {
    instance.nextAction.subscribe(row => CurrentComponent.isColumnNameClick = true);
    }
  }
```

}

Finally, in selectDataRow($event) function, you can check

```
selectDataRow(event) {
         if(CurrentComponent.isColumnNameClick) {
             CurrentComponent.isColumnNameClick = false;
              //access other row attributes using
               const id= event.data.id 
        }
}
```